# how to convert 4 lines block text to 1 line space interrupted

Tags: text-editing

I have a text file (name, surname, phone number)
than I would import in excel and the play with column (name, surname...)

The file was previously a docx file.
I've converted it on as a text file.
But the converted txt file, has a strange format:
Repeated 6 lines block, with each field (name, surname, phone, town)

```
xxx
yyy
999
zzz
xxx1
yyy1
```

repeated more times.
I would compact each block in a single line and separate field by space.
NOTE that `xxx1` and `yyy1` are name and surname of next person
So I can import it in Excel, taking space as a separator column.

How can I do that?
I know I can do that in Lisp, but I do not know how.

Comment: You say "Repeated 6 lines block" but you mention 4 parts to each block.  Could you clarify how to reconcile this 4 vs 6 discrepency?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you could do that with a keyboard macro.

Place the cursor at the beginning i.e. the very first x.

Define the macro (and also transform the first block):

```
C-x (
C-SPC
C-n
C-n
C-n
M-%
C-q C-j RET
SPC RET
!
C-n
C-a
C-x )
```

Transform the rest by calling the macro until it fails.

```
C-u 0 C-x e
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try with `sed` (unix utility) and regular expressions.

Comment: I don't think you can do this[1] with `sed`, at least not easily. `awk` might be a more reasonable suggestion, but remember, this is an emacs group and the OP asked for a lisp solution (although I have been guilty of suggesting non-lisp, non-emacs solutions a couple of times in the past too :-) ). [1]BTW, it's not clear what "this" is: the question is unclear.

Comment: With some bad faith: `awk` is in Emacs through `eshell`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this

```lisp
(defun my-join-n-lines (n)
  (dotimes (_ (1- n))
    (delete-indentation t))
  (forward-line))

(defun my-join-lines-loop ()
  (interactive "*")
  (while (= 0 (my-join-n-lines 4))))
```

The first function joins `n` lines, where `n` is the argument with which the function is called. The second one, which you can call with `M-x my-join-lines-loop`, calls `my-join-n-lines` with argument 4 until the buffer ends. Make sure to call it from the first line of a block otherwise it will merge all the lines with an offset with respect to your desired block-splitting.

You can make `my-join-lines-loop` accept a prefix argument by using this definition instead of the simpler one above,

```lisp
(defun my-join-lines-loop (&optional n)
  (interactive "P*")
  (while (= 0 (my-join-n-lines (or n 4)))))
```

Here the argument is optional and defaults to 4.